# Syntax error in SQL where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am very new to SQL and am writing a script to pull transactions that occur before 9/30/2015.  I received an error message - Incorrect syntax near keyword 'WHERE'.

What am I doing wrong?

```
    SELECT
     T1.Account,
T2.AcctName,
     SUM(T1.Debit - T1.Credit)  AS 'Balance',
     Sum(T1.SysDeb - T1.SysCred) AS 'USDBalance'
FROM OJDT T0 
INNER JOIN JDT1 T1 ON T0.TransId = T1.TransId
Left Join OACT T2 ON T2.AcctCode = T1.Account
GROUP BY 
T1.Account, T2.AcctName WHERE T1.Refdate <= '09-30-2015'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `WHERE` comes before the `GROUP BY`:

```
Select      T1.Account,
            T2.AcctName,
            Sum(T1.Debit - T1.Credit)   As 'Balance',
            Sum(T1.SysDeb - T1.SysCred) As 'USDBalance'
From        OJDT    T0 
Inner Join  JDT1    T1  ON  T0.TransId = T1.TransId
Left Join   OACT    T2  ON  T2.AcctCode = T1.Account
Where       T1.Refdate <= '09-30-2015'
Group By    T1.Account, T2.AcctName
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly. I appreciate you taking the time to respond

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `CROSS APPLY` to simplify some of the complexity of the `GROUP BY`.  Underneath, this code executes and returns the same result as the above answer.

```
SELECT
     balances.Account,
     balances.AcctName,
     balances.Balance  AS 'Balance',
     balances.USDBalance AS 'USDBalance'
FROM OJDT T0 
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT 
        SUM(T1.Debit - T1.Credit)  AS Balance,
        Sum(T1.SysDeb - T1.SysCred) AS USDBalance,
        T1.Account AS Account,
        T2.AcctName AS AcctName
    FROM JDT1 T1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN OACT T2 ON T2.AcctCode = T1.Account
    WHERE T1.TransId = T0.TransId AND T1.Refdate <= '09-30-2015'
) balances
```